# C# lambda GroupJoin but Group by another column

Tags: c#, asp.net, lambda, many-to-many, selectlist

So, I'm making a little program with ASP.NET Entity Framework. These are the relevant Models:

```
public class Tops
{
    public Tops()
    {
        Dresses = new HashSet<Dresses>();
    }

    [Key] public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int material { get; set; }
    public int meter { get; set; }

    public Inventory materialNavigation { get; set; }
    public Parts_material PartNavigation { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Dresses> Dresses { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Parts_material
{
    public Parts_material()
    {
        Tops = new HashSet<Tops>();
        Sleeves = new HashSet<Sleeves>();
        Patterns = new HashSet<Patterns>();
    }

    public int part_id { get; set; }
    public int material_id { get; set; }

    public Material MaterialNavigation { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Tops> Tops { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Sleeves> Sleeves { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Patterns> Patterns { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Material
{
    public Material()
    {
        Parts_Materials = new HashSet<Parts_material>();
        Inventories = new HashSet<Inventory>();
    }

    public int material_id { get; set; }
    public string material_name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Parts_material> Parts_Materials { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Inventory> Inventories { get; set; }

}
```

As you can see, there is a many-to-may-relation between `Tops` and `Material`. If I want to create a new Top, I want to select the materials with a SelectList. The lambda query I've so far is this:

```
var parts_Materials = _context.Parts_Material.GroupJoin(_context.Materials,
                                                        parts => parts.material_id,
                                                        material => material.material_id,
                                                        (parts, material) => new { Parts_material = parts.part_id, Material = material })
                                             .Select(e => new {
                                                 material_code = e.Material.Select(a => a.material_id),
                                                 material_name = String.Join(", ", e.Material.Select(a => a.material_name))
                                             })
                                             .ToList();

ViewData["material"] = new SelectList(parts_Materials, "material_code", "material_name");
```

The problem is that, if I understand this right, this wil group by `Parts_material.material_id`, but I want it to be grouped by `Parts_material.part_id`.
I'm struggeling with this for a few days now, so I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated** as it is clarified that `Tops.material` is actually `Parts_material.part_id`.

Expected output with sample data from comments:

```html
<select name="part">
    <option value="1">Kant</option>
    <option value="2">Kant, Jersey</option>
</select>
```

You need to group separately *after* joining, rather than group-joining in one go.

```cs
ViewData["part"] = new SelectList(
    from pm in _context.Parts_Material
    join m in _context.Materials on pm.material_id equals m.material_id
    group m.material_name by pm.part_id into names
    select new
    {
        part_id = names.Key,
        material_name = string.Join(", ", names)
    }
, "part_id", "material_name");
```

That `group` line means to group material names by part ID into an `IGrouping<>` that maps part ID to an `IEnumerable<>` of material names. Then each group is flattened into an anonymous type with the value and text content for an `<option>`.

I suggest that you rename `material` to `part` to avoid future confusion.

Comment: Yes, you understand me correctly, the first part is exactly want I want. I have one Top with, let's say, two different materials which I want to combine and gave me a string with the name of the materials, seperated by ", ".

I copied your answer in my project, but I changed the select part, because it gave an error. It said that `material_id` and `material_name` because "it didn't exist in current context". So I changed them to `m.material_id` and `m.material_name` respectively. It removed the error, but didn't what I wanted. I will give an expample in the next reply.

Comment: In addition to my last comment, I will give you an example.
I have now two materials: Kant and Jersey. The `Parts_materials` I do have now, are 
1. only Kant
2. Kant AND Jersey

I have a view to create new `Tops`, where I have to select which materials it is made of, and I want to do that with the SelectList. That means, the list I want to have, is:
1. Kant
2. Kant, Jersey

The number in the column `Tops.material` is the number in `Parts_material.part_id`, which corresponds with the (combination of) materials used for that Top.

Comment: I see. You actually want to select materials by part. I will update the answer soon.

Comment: Hope the updated answer solves your problem. If not, please provide expected HTML output.